# Firebase hosting showing generic message

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I was building a WhatsApp clone app (https://github.com/adrielwerlich/curso-hcode-whatsapp-clone)

1. running the build command
2. run the firebase deploy --only hosting command

But this screen is what I´m getting

[image]

And the Firebase dashboard is displaying

[image]

## Update

I was able to make some advances.

I added to

## webpack.config.js

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: './index.html',
})
```

and now there is proper html content...
but the app.bundle.js is giving a error message when I try to use `firebase serve`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After discovering that the bundle was only creating the js files, and was necessary to also configure the HtmlWebpackPlugin to create the HTML file the problem was to make the js files visible to the html files.

So the final solution to make the bundle run inside local `firebase serve` command and remote firebase hosting service...

The whole issue was about the webpack bundle config

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry:{
        app:'./src/app.js',
        'pdf.worker':'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry.js'
    },
    output:{
        filename:'[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        publicPath:'/' // the issue was here. Instead of /dist only / makes the js bundle files visible inside the html index file
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
                // include: __dirname + '/'
            },
            {
                test: /.(gif|png|jpe?g|webp|svg)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                   {
                     loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                     options: {
                       webp: {
                         quality: 80
                       }
                     }
                   }
                 ]
            }
        ],
      },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
          })
    ]
}
```

and also had to configure de css-style loader and the image webpack loader in order to run properly inside firebase localhost server and firebase remote hosting service

Suffering with the small details of bundle builder configuration... many hours of anxiety...